# Need an image/shape at the position of mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am currently working on a research project and I need a little help. Since I am just a novice in JS/Highcharts, the issue may seem basic to many. I want to display a circle at the mouse position (i.e. whenever mouse hovers on the chart).

And when I click the mouse (mousedown) I want the circle to stick in that position, and thereafter the circle does not follow the mouse position but remains stuck in the mouseclick position.

I believe that the circle can be made using [renderer.circle()](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Renderer.circle%28%29). And the mouse position can be  obtained from jQuery [function](http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/). But I need a logic to incorporate them inside HighStocks.

Any help will be appreciated. If you can provide solution based on the demo link(jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/candlestick/)  then thats will be amazing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not perfect (a little choppy), but the following should get you started:

```
// setup `chart` object ...

var circle = chart.renderer.circle(0, 0, 5).attr({
    fill: 'blue',
    stroke: 'black',
    'stroke-width': 1
}).add()
  .toFront()
  .hide();

var stuck = false;

$(chart.container).mousemove(function(event){
    circle.show();

    if (stuck) {
        return;
    }

    circle.attr({
        x: event.offsetX,
        y: event.offsetY
    });
});

$(chart.container).click(function(event){
    stuck = true;

    circle.attr({
        x: event.offsetX,
        y: event.offsetY
    });
});
```

Here it is in action: http://jsfiddle.net/Ukh5j/

Comment: Thats a nice answer. Will explore it further so as to reduce the snapping of the circle.

Comment: It was easy. Replaced 'mouseover' by 'mousemove' and voila - its working smoothly. Thanks a ton for your answer.

Comment: Great! I updated my answer with the 'mousemove' change. Glad to help :)

Comment: Just a small niggle. Was testing with my mobile and it didn't work because the solution is using jquery events. However the touch event of highcharts (crosshairs) is working. Is there a way to use high chart event rather than jquery events?

Comment: I haven't tested this on a mobile device, but you can try using the click event handler for placing the circle on the chart: [http://jsfiddle.net/BbkrR/](http://jsfiddle.net/BbkrR/). I don't know of any equivalent for mousemove, but that's probably not applicable for mobile devices anyway.

Comment: Is there a way to compare the mouseposition with xAxis position instead if offsetX ? Just asked this question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15152738/highcharts-highlight-mouse-position-within-a-range