# Highcharts - highlight mouse position within a range

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need to highlight mouse position when mouse is within a xAxis range of a line chart in HIighCharts. 
I want to display a circle to highlight the mouse position. But I want this functionality only for the last 25 xAxis values.

Is it possible to do this in Highcharts?

One way is by following code but it has its limitations:

```
var circle = chart.renderer.circle(0, 0, 5).attr({
    fill: 'blue',
    stroke: 'black',
        'stroke-width': 1
}).add()
    .toFront()
    .hide();

$(chart.container).mousemove(function (event) {
        circle.attr({
            x: event.offsetX,
            y: event.offsetY
        });
        if (event.offsetX > SOME_VALUE) circle.show();
    });
```

The shortcomings are that I am comparing event.offsetX instead of event.xAxis[0].value i.e. I am comparing the xValue of mouse in page rather than xAxis value in chart.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `point.plotX` and `chart.plotLeft` to get position on a chart, see: http://jsfiddle.net/PNMAG/35/

Snippet:

```
function addCircle() {
  var chart = this;
  var circle = chart.renderer.circle(0, 0, 5).attr({
      fill: 'blue',
      stroke: 'black',
      'stroke-width': 1
    }).add()
    .toFront()
    .hide();

  $(chart.container).mousemove(function(event) {
    var normalizedEvent = chart.pointer.normalize(event);

    if (normalizedEvent.chartX > chart.series[0].data[5].plotX + chart.plotLeft) {
      circle.attr({
        x: normalizedEvent.chartX,
        y: normalizedEvent.chartY
      }).show();
    } else {
      circle.hide();
    }
  });
}
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
  chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    type: 'area',
    events: {
      load: addCircle
    }
  },
  series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
  }, {
    data: [71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 20]
  }]
});
```

Comment: Again a perfect answer from you. No way could I have found this answer by myself as I did not get a solution through google and neither by browsing the api docs. Thanks a ton!

Comment: An afterthought. For s specific mouse position, is it possible to find the values of x,y co-ordinate on the chart ? i.e. for a particular offsetX find the corresponding xAxis value?

Comment: Yes, you can use `translate` function, this is not part of API, but possible to use: `chart.x/yAxis[index].translate()`. Arguments for function you can find in source code after: `Translate from axis value to pixel position on the chart, or back`

Comment: Your JSFiddle example is highly appreciated. This is great for doing things like highlighting an area of a chart (using renderer.rect() ) and not having to worry about zIndex issues. Mouse tracking was perfect for my issue.

Comment: As another note, I had some layering issues/cross browser issues that were solved by using `event = chart.pointer.normalize(event)` so that child/parent events would be handled correctly with a "mousemove" event

Comment: You are right! Updated demo in the answer. Using `event.chartX` and `event.chartY` is a better solution.